# Concatenate columns if not equal

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using the following `SELECT` query to generate a resulting column based on two columns:

```
SELECT colA + '(' + colB + ')' AS formattedCol from mytable WHERE ...
```

However if the value of `colA` and `colB` is equal I need to just have the value of `colA`.

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: In MS Access, the string concatenator is & not +, you will get a null returned if one of the columns is null.

Comment: It's all gone a bit mad on this one, let's end it with, IIF is the best solution here and Remou's answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noted, @Andrew, IIf is used by MS Access, so:

```
SELECT IIf([colA] = [colB], [colA], [colA] & '(' & colB & ')') AS formattedCol 
FROM mytable WHERE
```

Note that the string concatenator in MS Access is &, not +. Using + can cause a null to be returned when a column is null.

Comment: You may want to fix up your own answer before downvoting others :-)

Comment: @paxdiabolo What have you got against it? It runs in MS Access, yesno :)

Comment: (I would like to see how quickly I was downvoted if I posted an Access solution on an SQL Server question :D )

Comment: I have no problem with the technical content of your answer, just that dangling bit at the end :-) "When" what exactly?

Comment: @paxdiabolo "when I get these SQL Server devotee guys alone ... >: " ?

Comment: That's better. On the assumption that you're right about the concatenation (my answer was a more generic-SQL one), I'll give you a +1 for that. I'm still not a big fan of per-row functions (including `case` and `iif`) but it's unlikely to matter for MsAccess databases, which I suspect tend to be small compared to the behemoths we manage on the mainframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN colA = colB
        THEN colA
        ELSE colA + '(' + colB + ')'
    END AS formattedCol from mytable WHERE ...
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in Access but I did it with `IIF`. Thanks

Comment: SQL is a generic tag and does not refer to SQL server. This answer will never work with MS Access, which is the type of SQL requested by the OP.

Comment: Did you miss the part that said "Is there a way to do this in SQL?"

Comment: Did you miss the part that says SQL is generic? There is Jet SQL, Oracle SQL, etc. In Access, "to do this in SQL" means in ACE/Jet SQL as opposed to say, VBA.